# Issue with timezone attributes in R

Tags: r, timezone

Ive noticed a change in the way R presents some timezone attributes.  For example:

- date/time objects with the timezone "America/New_York" present the time zone attribute "EST" (consistent with the format code %Z).  This has always been the case and is still the case
- other timezones, such as "Asia/Qatar" no longer present the familiar attribute "AST" (for Arabic standard time) as seen previously, but now present "+03".

Why is that and what has changed?  When I try to format date/time objects to use the %Z format, I still get "+03" not "AST".

This line shows the issue in practice:

```
> format(as.POSIXct(Sys.time()), format = "%Z", tz = "Asia/Qatar")
```

[1] "+03"

This might seem trivial, but legacy code that expects "AST" will no longer work. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: as.POSIXct gives AST on R 3.2.3. What function you use to format date/time?

Comment: Things were fine with 3.2.  I saw the change following a recent upgrade to 3.4.2.

Answer (score 2):

The source for time zone data in R, and most other computing platforms, is the [IANA time zone database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).  The maintainers of the this data started in 2016, and continuing into 2017, meticulously going through every time zone abbreviation, removing any that they deem "invented", and replacing it with a fixed numeric offset.

By "invented", understand that at earlier times in its history, it was acceptable for the database maintainers to just make up something that seemed reasonable for a time zone abbreviation when there wasn't one naturally used in the real world.   This practice has now stopped, and is being reverted, because it was recognized that the database is there to *record* time zone information from the world, not invent it.

In other words, while the `Asia/Qatar` time zone entry previously had "GST" as an abbreviation for times before 1972, and "AST" as an abbreviation for times from there to present, neither abbreviation is *actually* used in Qatar.  At least, not to the best knowledge of the database maintainers.

That particular change was made in tzdb 2017a.  [Announcement here.](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2017-February/000045.html)

Comment: The issue is clear now and makes sense.  Thanks for the explanation and the link to the original material.  A good day to you!